# pygame.error: display Surface quit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

В это коде:

```
import sys
import pygame


def run_Game():
    # Инициализирует игру
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(1280, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    # Основной цикл игры
    while True:

        # Отслеживание событий клавиатуры и мыши
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit():
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()


run_Game()
```

строчка:
`screen.fill(bg_color)`
Выдает ошибку: *pygame.error: display Surface quit*

Но если её убрать, то:

`pygame.display.flip()`
Выдает ошибку:  *pygame.error: video system not initialized*

Comment: Вы знаете, что делает данная строка? `if event.type == pygame.quit():`

Comment: Да, проверяет если перехватанный ивент является закрытием программы, то выполняется код дальше.

Comment: Нет, это закрывает pygame и сравнивает `event.type` с `None`. Найдите различие между вашим кодом и [этим](https://younglinux.info/pygame/framework)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое. Просто только сегодня начал изучать данную библиотеку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылаясь на [документацию](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit), `pygame.quit()` - Отменяет инициализацию всех модулей pygame, которые были ранее инициализированы. В вашем же случае надо использовать `pygame.QUIT`. [здесь](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) документация событий.

Также, ссылаясь на [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), вызов sys.exit() будет вызывать ошибку `SystemExit`, в случае pygame рекомендуется завести переменную `run`, и менять её значение. Такой подход будет чище и правильнее.

В итоге, ваш код должен выглядеть вот так:

```py
import pygame


def run_Game():
    # Инициализирует игру
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(1280, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    run = True

    # Основной цикл игры
    while run:

        # Отслеживание событий клавиатуры и мыши
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = not run

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()


run_Game()
```

Если вы считаете, что вам не подходит этот вариант, вот решение с `sys.exit`:

```py
import sys
import pygame


def run_Game():
    # Инициализирует игру
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(1280, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    # Основной цикл игры
    while True:

        # Отслеживание событий клавиатуры и мыши
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit(0)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()


run_Game()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Krikozyabra если вы считаете мой ответ полезным, вы можете проголосовать за него (треугольник вверх)